# Redirect bought domain from hetzner to heroku application

Tags: heroku, dns, cname, mx-record

I have purchased a domain from hetzner. Currently my application is running on my heroku account. My question ist. How to redirect the domain from `hertzner` to my `heroku` application. I can only use these records:

[image]

I really appreciate your answers, cause I really have no idea where to start!

PS.: I can only use the `DNS records` because  I have only aquired a domain and therefore the panel `http://myaccount.hetzner.co.za` is not available for me ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Heroku Dev Center article has many answers regarding DNS:

- [Heroku DevCenter: Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

In short: you want any apex domain (mydomain.com) to **forward** to a subdomain (typically www.mydomain.com), and then **CNAME** the subdomain to your Heroku app.

```
mydomain FORWARD www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com CNAME something.herokuapp.com
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Would you be so kind to descripe the exact CNAME input for my form fields. I tried it, however it(`Hostname: www, CNAME, my-heroku-app.heroku.com`) does not seem to work...